# Jenkins build docker image fail with non-zero code: 137

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs, requirements.txt

My Jenkins **build docker image** pipeline fails when it runs `RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

the logs show that it installs the requirements but when it gets to the last few, it gives the following error:

```
/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

I see that code means low on memory, however this error has never occurred before. The Jenkins server sits in AWS. Do I need to make in RAM adjustments there?

Comment: You have tagged ECS. are you running Jenkins as container on ECS cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to upgrade the ec2 instance with more RAM